# php MySqli_query постоянно возвращает boolean ошибку

Tags: php, sql

Скрипт ниже возвращает постоянно ошибку

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in

Сам скрипт

```
    protected function removeUsersAction(){

    $dateToday = time(); 

    $dateOverdue = $dateToday - 24*60*60; // Вычитаем 24 часа так, как это уже просроченное время регистрации!

    $query = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_status`='0' AND `user_reg_date` < '".$dateOverdue."'";

    $res = mysqli_query($this->db_connect, $query); 

    if ( $res == true && mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

        $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        do{
            $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '".$res['user_id']."'";
            $delRes = mysqli_query($this->db_connect, $deleteQuery);

            if ( !$delRes )
                $this->errors[] = "Ошибка SQL! пользователя не удалить!";

        }while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
    } else
        $this->errors[] = "Пользователей для удаления нету!";

}
```

В чем ошибка понять не могу, если есть вопрос по $this->db_connect, то это переменная подключения к базе данных во всех других случаях  все ок с ней.

PS! Метод для исполнения прописан в конструкторе __construct

Comment: $this->db_connect как создается, здается мне, что подключение не установилось и db_connect это false.

Comment: дело в том, что в классе есть другие методы типа authAction(); там используется тоже mysqli_query именно с таким же вариантом и все ок. а исполнение метода выше прописанно в конструкторе может из-за этого?

Comment: Коннекшн где создается. Метод должен вызываться после установки соединения с БД

Comment: коннект создается в самом начале.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in

Дословно - ожидается объект базы, но приехал boolean. Это может быть в случае не удачной установки соединения к БД

Comment: Я понял в чем дело, Дело в том, что у меня сперва запускался метод в конструкторе и в db_connect шло, что по умолчанию (false), а потом переменной db_connect передавалось соединение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in
Функция ожидает коннекшн к БД, но приехал bool.
Это возможно, когда коннекшн провалился.

Comment: ок спасибо за дельный совет, пригодится в решении некоторых проблем . напроверку

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем дело в том, что у меня сперва запускался метод в конструкторе и в db_connect шло, что по умолчанию (false), а потом переменной db_connect передавалось соединение